# What is memory, vcores and disks on yarn scheduler page?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Can someone explain used resources, Min resources and Max Resources in detailed ? With all specific details about the memory units ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yarn *scheduler* is the component which is responsible for managing the *queues*. It interacts with a component called *resource manager* to request allocation of resources for *applications* in those queues, which come in the form of *containers*. Every such component is a world of its own, and while it takes some time to grasp the entire framework, a detailed explanation of those resource requests may be found [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html).

Comment: Your link is for Capacity Scheduler but the screenshot is from Fair Scheduler.  Note the `Steady Fair Share` in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Your used resources says you used 2 virtual cores with 6GB of memory total.  This means YARN gave you 2 containers with a total memory of 6GB.

Min Resources and Max Resources are best explained by Ray Chiang and Dennis Dawson in [Untangling Apache Hadoop YARN, Part 4: Fair Scheduler Queue Basics](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/06/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-4-fair-scheduler-queue-basics/):

> - The minResources limit is a soft limit. It is enforced as long as the queue total resource requirement is greater than or equal to the minResources requirement and it will get at least the amount specified as long as the following holds true:
>
>   - The resources are available or can be preempted from other queues.
>   - The sum of all minResources is not larger than the cluster’s total resources.
> - The maxResources limit is a hard limit, meaning it is constantly enforced. The total resources used by the queue with this property plus any of its child and descendant queues must obey the property.